# Redirect bad url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all bad requests to another url that i identify. For example, if the user type `http://www.mywebsite.com/unavailablepage.html`, he will not get 404 page, instead, he will be redirected to another url. How can i do that in the `.htaccess` file? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorDocument 404 /your_page.html`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your .htaccess file, changing /404.php to the location of your actual 404 page.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

See http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/ for more details.